# Select one or more files from one <input type="file" />

Tags: javascript, html

I want the output to be as follows (pictured)

[image]

In the image above, the user can select several different files from just one "choose file" and view the file name below. The user can also delete it!

I just know it below, that we have to increase the number of inputs to select two or more files!

```html
<input type="file" />
```

Can it be solved using JavaScript?

please guide me. If you have a source please tell.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/multiple#file_input?

Comment: The code that you have shown is not the code with that you created the image. Please share the code you use. Normally, if the `multiple` attribute isn' set on an input, the user can only select one file, but it seems like you are using a library...?

Comment: @Apollo79 please check this question => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71488349/how-to-get-one-or-more-files-in-one-input-type-file-multiple