# how to get one or more files in one <input type="file" multiple />

Tags: javascript, html, forms, file, input

It's confusing to me, I want to get one or more files using an input with `multiple` attribute.

I have created the following form:

```html
<form method="get">
  <input type="file" name="file" multiple />
  <br /><br />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

When I select a file and submit the form, at the end of the URL and after the question mark(?) it shows:

**?file=fileName.jpg**

My problem is that if the user selects two files, they must show both in the URL. Like the following:

**?file=fileName.jpg&anotherFileName.jpg**

I can actually have more than one file. But no matter how many files I select, it only shows one.

This is not what I'm looking for, it only shows selected photos (http://jsfiddle.net/0GiS0/Yvgc2/).
But I want to submit all the files in the form, using only one `<input type="file" />`

Comment: Hi Mordad, what are you expecting from submitting this form? You've set the `method` to `GET`, which means there won't be any posted body. If you're intending to upload selected files from the client's local machine this won't work. When I run your code in Edge, I do get multiple file _names_ in the query string: `my/test/index.html?file=a.txt&file=b.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

`input type="file" name="file" multiple="true"`

Comment: I tried and it does not work

Comment: Hi vonka11, as you've written it this post doesn't add much to the question. It is flagged for deletion but given you're new you might want the chance to improve it. I would suggest trying out the solution yourself, perhaps in jsfiddle or similar, and then post the full html and javascript or a link to your fiddle, before posting. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
<form method="get" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file" multiple="TRUE" />
    <br /><br />
    <input type="submit" />
  </form>
```

for got to add multiple = true
[image]

Comment: Did you really come to this conclusion? I copied your code exactly and got no result. thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
  <input type="file" name="file" multiple>
  <br /><br />
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Use post and multipart format to upload files

Comment: Thank you, but that was not my answer

Answer (score -1):

You may want to look at these similar problems:

Put brackets after the name attribute

```
<input id="image" type="file" name="images[]" multiple="multiple">
```

link:

[Multiple file uploader only sends one file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14007243/multiple-file-uploader-only-sends-one-file)

and

Use the [files property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file) of that element:

```
var elem = document.getElementById("id_upload");
var names = [];
for (var i = 0; i < elem.files.length; ++ i) {
   names.push(elem.files[i].name);
}
```

link:

[Retrieving file names out of a multi-file upload control with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3654179/retrieving-file-names-out-of-a-multi-file-upload-control-with-javascript)

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)